# XEP-0133: Admin request to get all online users list

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, openfire

I tried with strophe.js by using iq method, and I can able to get the number of online users, but I'm not able to get the online user list from my Openfire 3.9.3 server.

**XMPP request body:**

```xml
<iq from='admin@localhost/7adf302e' to='admin@localhost' type='set' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client' id='6816:sendIQ'>
  <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list' />
</iq>
```

**XMPP response**

```xml
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="6816:sendIQ" from="admin@localhost" to="admin@localhost/7adf302e">
  <command xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands" node="http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list"/>
  <error code="404" type="cancel">
    <item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

Ref:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#get-online-users-list

Answer (score 1):

As described in [XEP-0050](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html), an `item-not-found` error response to a command request means that "The responding JID cannot find the requested command node", i.e. the server doesn't support the command for getting the list of online users.

From a quick glance at the Openfire source code, it seems like it does support the [Get List of Active Users](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#get-active-users-list) command at the node `http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-active-users`.  It looks like this command just returns the users connected to the server, so I'm not sure if this is different in any way from the "get all online users" command in this case.

Comment: By referring XEP-0050, I’m able to getting list of all admin commands. But I need to execute more command described in XEP-0133. Is there a way to add more command?.

Comment: That depends on what server you're using.

Comment: I'm using Openfire 3.9.3 server.

Comment: Looks like there is an alternative command in Openfire; see updated answer.